# How to use a "custom jar" in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, configuration, intellij-idea, ide, dependencies

I'm trying to set up IntelliJ IDEA -- tried 12 and 13 -- Mac to use a Java class included a jar file for my Java application.

I've set the jar as a module dependency by the following procedure

- Start from the "project window";
- Select my main Java module;
- Use menu File | Project Structure;
- In Project Settings, select Modules, and select my Java application as interested module in the middle window;
- On the window to the right, select "Dependencies" tab, and press "+" and select "Jars or directories" and navigate to the jar file, add select it so the custom jar file is added as a new entry in the window, check the Export checkbox and set Scope pulldown set as "Compile";
- Press OK.

However, after setting this, in a Java class file in my Java application, if I use a class defined in the custom jar file, it still prompts me "Cannot resolve symbol 'SomeClass'".

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

Edit:

my settings:

[image]

[image]

BTW, the Libraries and Global libraries are both empty.  I tried to set the two jars there (separately) and add them as dependencies for the Java app, and had no luck, so I deleted them from Libraries and Global libraries. The above setting is using add module dependency as files directly (without first registering them as libraries), which still does not work.

Comment: Try to invalidate caches from menu. And one crazy idea - check that jar really contains that class

Comment: The class does exist.  After invalidating cache, the same issue remains.

Comment: What you're describing should work. Can you post in screenshots the module dependencies and project structure

Comment: Everything looks correctly for me. I advise to get help from jetbrains people here http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting everything in the default unnamed package solved the issue.