# IntelliJ added Project libraries doesn't work in packages

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libraries

First of all, my problem is exactly like [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25601034/intellij-external-library-dependence-within-packages) and [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671848/how-to-use-a-custom-jar-in-intellij-idea).

However question2 only find a workaround.(which works, thanks) But that doesn't solve the problem.

And question1 only cited instructions from IntelliJ website, which I followed exactly. However the problem still exist.

Here is the problem:

I have added two jars to the `Project Structure` - `Project Settings` - `Libraries`.

They are shown correctly in `Project Structure` - `Project Settings` - `Modules` - `[mymodule]` - `Dependencies` and in the `Project` - `External Libraries` dropdown.

However, for classes inside a package, the libraries seems invisible. But for file created directly in the module folder, the libraries works just fine.

(See below screensnap) (`BinaryOut` is a legitimate class in algs4.jar)

[image]

Also, `Invalidate Cache` doesn't help.

So how should I config the libraries so that they can work inside packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the fault of the library you are using:

> Q. If I use a named package to structure my code, the compiler can no longer access the libraries in stdlib.jar. Why not?
>
> A. The libraries in stdlib.jar are in the "default" package. In Java, you can't access classes in the default package from a named package. If you need to use our libraries with a named package, you can use the packaged version [stdlib-package.jar](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/stdlib-package.jar).

[Source](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/)

Comment: My god Huge thanks. Finally this is solved. I've seen this question in SO for at least three times. So whenever I want to create a library that can be used in a package, I have to put those classes in a package, not directly under the "default" "unnamed"(?) package? Then I create the jar file, Right?

Comment: Yes, you should always put your Java classes into your own, unique package.